# Only get the version number from set of lines

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, grep

How to get only the version from set of lines?

These are the lines inn flat file:

```
./org.jamon/jamon-runtime/jars/jamon-runtime-2.3.1.jar
./org.apache.ftpserver/ftplet-api/bundles/ftplet-api-1.0.0.jar
./org.clojars.jasonjckn/kafka_2.9.2/jars/kafka_2.9.2-0.7.2-test1.jar
./org.apache.ftpserver/ftpserver-deprecated/jars/ftpserver-deprecated-1.0.0-M2.jar
./org.codehaus.jettison/jettison/bundles/jettison-1.1.jar
./stax/stax-api/jars/stax-api-1.0.1.jar
```

Output:

```
 2.3.1
 1.0.0
 0.7.2-test1
 1.0.0-M2
 1.1
```

Comment: You could start by removing everything that does not look like a version number.

Answer (score 3):

For a **sed** solution:

```
sed 's/.*-\([0-9][0-9.]*[^\/]*\)\.jar$/\1/'
```

Explanation:

- Replace: anything + hyphen + `revision` + ".jar" with just the `revision`, where:
- The the `revision` is identified as: starts with number, followed by numbers or dots, followed by *any* text except slash `/`, and is preceded by a hyphen `-`.
- ".jar" must be at the end-of-line.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `grep` with `-P` option (PCRE regex for look ahead and behind):

```
grep -oP '(?<=-)[0-9.]+[-[:alnum:]]*(?=\.jar)' file
2.3.1
1.0.0
0.7.2-test1
1.0.0-M2
1.1
1.0.1
```

As suggested [cbuckley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23686625/only-get-the-version-number-from-set-of-lines/23686825#comment36393944_23686825) in the comments more generic way of saying it would be (will work if you files have extensions other than `.jar`:

```
grep -oP '(?<=-)[\d.]+[-\w]*(?=\.\w+)' file
```

Comment: +1 — was just about to post almost the same, so I'll save adding another answer, but for the record my regex was `(?<=-)[\d.]+[-\w]*(?=\.\w+)`.

Comment: Thanks @cbuckley, have added your suggestion to the answer. You are right no need for POSIX character class if the `grep` supports `-P` option.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
awk -F/ '{n=split($NF,a,"-");if (a[n-1]~/[0-9.]+/) a[n]=a[n-1]"-"a[n];sub(/\.jar$/,"",a[n]);print a[n]}' file
2.3.1
1.0.0
0.7.2-test1
1.0.0-M2
1.1
1.0.1
```

If you have `gnu grep` use the Jaypal's solution :), this `awk` should work on most system.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is

```
grep -Po "(?<=-)\d[^/]*(?=\.jar$)"
```